# How to use ImageCapture in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot of the entire visible page of an Ionic Vue app, but I get the error "Cannot find name 'ImageCapture'".

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
      const screenVideoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
      console.log("screenVideoTrack", screenVideoTrack);
      const capture = new ImageCapture(screenVideoTrack); // here the error occurs
      // when you need the still image
      const bitmap = await capture.grabFrame();
      // if you want a Blob version
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      if (!canvas) {
        console.error("no canvas created");
        return;
      }
      canvas.width = bitmap.width;
      canvas.height = bitmap.height;
      canvas.getContext("bitmaprenderer")?.transferFromImageBitmap(bitmap);
      const blob = await new Promise((res) => canvas.toBlob(res));
```

I did install the ""@types/w3c-image-capture": "^1.0.5"," via npm. The error occurs while compiling not while executing (cannot execute if not correctly compiled).

How do I mage Ionic Vue aware, that this type does exist?

Is there an alternative to take a screenshot of the entire page?
(the lib 'html2canvas' is no option for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886458/error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-imagecapture-and-already-installed-types-w3c-i) to mine on StackOverflow and followed the answer given by [Paweł Ciucias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5626477/pawe%C5%82-ciucias). I had to manually add the lib to the tsconfig.json file under 'compileroptions -> types'

```
"types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest",
      "w3c-image-capture"
    ],
```

The error now disappeared!